# Searching old news articles

Tags: search, google-news

[Google News advanced search](http://news.google.com/news/advanced_news_search) only lets me search news article by date from the last month.

Is there any similar site where I can search for news articles or trends by date for the last decade or so? I'm especially interested in times of early Iraq War (2003-2006).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you search for "Iraq war" on [News.google.com](http://news.google.com/news/search?aq=f&pz=1&jfkl=true&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&q=iraq%20war), you'll see "Archives" option on the left pane under "Any recent news".

Clicking on it will bring new [options](http://www.google.com/search?jfkl=true&hl=en&q=iraq%20war&sa=N&tbs=nws:1,ar:1) as follows:

[image]

You can either click on any year or click on "Custom Range..." to select a range. This is the result for your case:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Now that you've shown me where it is, I don't know how I could have missed it.

Comment: @taw: You're welcome. It's a pity that the germane option is not available in _Advanced Search_.

Comment: I asked on Google Forums (http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/news/thread?tid=3a3ee917c412ae9d&hl=en
), if it doesn't work I'll try poking my contacts within Google, maybe they'll add it.

Comment: @taw: Good point. I hope they add it.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the 'daterange:[startdate]-[enddate]' operator**

The only downside is that it uses the Julian date format.

Example:

```
searchterm daterange:2452000-2452435
```

A more detailed explanation of the 'daterange:' operator can be found @ [cnet](http://reviews.cnet.com/4520-10165_7-6206764-2.html?tag=rb_content;rb_mtx).